# UITextField textContentType doesn't return suggestion

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I am experiencing this rather simple problem and it is confusing me because my Contact Card is filled with email addresses of all (home, work, iCloud, other) where as the First Name, Last Name, Telephone Number are all being presented as **suggestions**. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
    emailTxtField.delegate = self
    emailTxtField.textContentType =.emailAddress
    phoneNumTxtField.delegate = self
    phoneNumTxtField.textContentType =.telephoneNumber
    firstNameTxtField.delegate = self
    firstNameTxtField.textContentType =.givenName
    lastNameTxtField.delegate = self
    lastNameTxtField.textContentType =.familyName
```

Every other fields are getting suggestions but not the email address. Please help?

**UPDATE**

Some snapshots:

[image]

and another
.
.
.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your emailTxtField.text is empty and doesn't contain let's say a space text?

Comment: 100% sure. I'll even attach some snapshots

Comment: Ok, how do you display your custom accessory input view for the keyboard with arrows and done button?

Comment: Well that is a third party called IQKeyboardManager: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Did you try the same with no IQKeyboardManager activated? And just make sure you're using the latest version, probably the issue was in there.

Comment: Yeah i have and still the same. I am surprised that it is fetching the telephoneNumber, givenName and familyName but not the email. I did however try in a different simple project with only IQKeyboardManager as pod and two textfields and tried the same and it DID return the email address even with the IQKeyboardManager activated and still it returned. I am confused why it won't return me the email address from the Contact Card in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
emailTxtField.textContentType = .username
emailTxtField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

Refer: [Apple's article: Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)